# Storing all Possible Permutations within R

Tags: r

I am using permutations command under "`gtools`". However, it produced memory problem.

I have tried the following:

```
library(gtools)
permutations(n=15,r=8)
```

However, I have got the following error message:

```
 Error in next_permutations(n, k, -1L, NULL, x, freq, replace, type) : 
cannot allocate vector of length 2075673600.
```

This is very basic of what I am doing. I need permutations lot more than `n=15` and `k=8`.

Comment: Strange.  Based on the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtools/gtools.pdf), your call should have worked.  `15 choose 8` is a relatively small number.

Comment: sorry it should be r. Thanks

Comment: @SamiUllah  If memory is the issue, then you may need to upgrade memory

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's not `15 choose 8`; it's `15!/8! = 32432400`

Comment: 0r maybe `n!/k!(n-k)!`

Comment: Oh, sorry, actually it's `15!/(15 - 8)! = 259,459,200`

Comment: Actually, there are many possibilities, if not  ordered and no repetitions are allowed then `n!/k!(n-k)! = 6435`. If ordered and no repetitions, then `n!/(n-k)!= 259459200`. If ordered and repetitions are allowed, then its `n power k = 2562890625`.

Comment: if you need to work with much larger sets it might be a good to idea to work with an iterator that can work through the set of permutations in a piecewise fashion, rather than generating and storing all of them once ...

Comment: @BenBolker can you please provide an example for the method you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer had two short-comings:

- It did only compute permutations of `1:r`.
- The number of permutations was wrong, since I used `n! / r!` instead of `n! / (n - r)!`.

The last point increases the size of the resulting matrix for `n = 15` and `r = 8` by a factor of 8 to about 8 GB. this highlights the point made by Ben Bolker in the comments: One should think about working through the permutations in an iterative fashion.

Anyway, a simple way to generate all permutations is to generate all combinations with `combn()` first. After that one can generate the permutations for each combination using `std::next_permutation` in C++:

```
src1 <- '
IntegerMatrix permute_combinations(const IntegerMatrix& combs) {
  size_t numComb(combs.cols());
  size_t r(combs.rows());
  size_t numPermPerComb(1);
  for(size_t i = 1; i <= r; ++i) numPermPerComb *= i;
  size_t numPerm = numComb * numPermPerComb;
  IntegerMatrix perms(numPerm, r);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < numComb; ++i) {
    IntegerVector v = combs(_, i);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < numPermPerComb; ++j) {
      perms(i * numPermPerComb + j, _) = v;
      std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end());
    }
  }
  return perms;
}
'

Rcpp::cppFunction(src1)
system.time(perms <- permute_combinations(combn(15, 8)))
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>      54.572       1.136      56.006
dim(perms)
#> [1] 259459200         8
object.size(perms)
#> 8302694600 bytes
head(perms)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
#> [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    8    7
#> [3,]    1    2    3    4    5    7    6    8
#> [4,]    1    2    3    4    5    7    8    6
#> [5,]    1    2    3    4    5    8    6    7
#> [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    8    7    6
tail(perms)
#>              [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#> [259459195,]   15   14   13   12   11    8    9   10
#> [259459196,]   15   14   13   12   11    8   10    9
#> [259459197,]   15   14   13   12   11    9    8   10
#> [259459198,]   15   14   13   12   11    9   10    8
#> [259459199,]   15   14   13   12   11   10    8    9
#> [259459200,]   15   14   13   12   11   10    9    8
```

### Original version

The resulting matrix is just below 1 GB, so there has to be some inefficiency in the gtools code. Here a quick & dirty C++ version for usage with Rcpp:

```
src <- 'IntegerMatrix permutations(int n, int r) {
  size_t numPerm(1);
  for(int i = n; i > r; --i) {
    numPerm *= i;
  }
  IntegerMatrix result(numPerm, r);

  IntegerVector v(r);
  std::iota (std::begin(v), std::end(v), 1);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numPerm; ++i) {
    result(i, _) = v;
    std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end());
  }
  return result;
}'
Rcpp::cppFunction(src)
system.time(perms <- permutations(15, 8))
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>       6.909       0.060       6.970
dim(perms)
#> [1] 32432400        8
object.size(perms)
#> 1037837000 bytes
head(perms)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
#> [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    8    7
#> [3,]    1    2    3    4    5    7    6    8
#> [4,]    1    2    3    4    5    7    8    6
#> [5,]    1    2    3    4    5    8    6    7
#> [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    8    7    6
```